# How to make app compatible for 3.5" and 4" retina display

Tags: ios, compatibility, retina-display

I have checked all relavent questions. Didn't find anything useful or may be I was not able to understand. I am newbie and just prepared a simple app.

App looks good for iPhone 5 screen as you can see below:
[image: iPhone 5 screen]

But on as I turn it 3.5 screen mode. It messes up with the element on the screen. as you can see below [image: 3.5 screen]

Can anyone help me how to fix it or just making two version of app is the best solution of this problem. 
Any help or suggest would be truly appreciated.

Comment: how do you position that button?

Comment: I am using Auto Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use the size inspector (option command 5). The autoresizing area is what you're looking for. The red box represents the selected object and will show where the app will place and stretch UI element relative to the window. The I shaped outer arrows show it's anchor point. The arrows in the middle show how the object will be stretched vertically or horizontally.

[image: Xcode's size inspector]

Comment: This would be a good answer, but it appears he is using constraints, so it will not apply.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could do this.  One way would be to create a second xib or storyboard file for the different screen size.  However, Apple added constraints to make it so you don't need to have a second file.  To edit the constraints, click on the ruler tab when editing the storyboard or xib.  You will find the constraints on the bottom.  For more help with constraints, you might try [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).